# JQuery Multiple Month Calendar View

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, calendar, schedule

I'm looking for suggestions/recommendations for a JQuery/Javascript calendar that can display multiple months at once (ie. previous month, current month, next month) like so:
[image: Image showing four calendars in a horizontal row with sequential months (Sept to Dec). Arrows on the right and left indicate the view can be scrolled. Some of the dates on each calendar have a border, or are coloured in different shades of blue.]

(The attached mockup shows a 4-month view, but I think we'll actually be doing a 3-month view).

I DO NOT need a date picker. This is basically meant to display a user's schedule, with no ability to choose a specific month/year (beyond the side-scrolling). We'll pull events out of our database, hook them into the calendar somehow, and then on a day click/hover (or both), display additional information. Events will not be editable from this view - it is display only.

I've looked into general JQuery calendar plugins (Ion Calendar, CLNDR), but none seem to have the basic multiple-month functionality I need. Multi-lingual support (or the ability to add multi-lingual text) is also important to us. I was really hoping to find a ready-made plugin for this - can't be the first time someone's tried to do it!

In case it's any use/help, we use ColdFusion and MSSQL Server. We've also got JQuery 1.9.1, JQueryUI 1.10.0 and Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Edit: I did look at the JQuery UI datepicker, but it won't work for the functionality I need. I can't see any way to attach data to a specific date, or to be able to style certain days differently than others. I think the primary issue w/ it is that it's a datepicker, not a display calendar.

Comment: Why not use ... wait for it .... The jQuery UI DatePicker. It's multilingual, can show three months, and all the rest of the stuff you seem to want ?

Comment: Because I don't need a datepicker and it doesn't have the multi-month scrolling features I need.

Comment: Then I guess you have to roll your own.

Comment: Well since I'd prefer to not have to do that, I made a post asking for suggestions.

Comment: It doesn't do the multiple month view, however given that you can't seem to find anything else, I'll suggest FullCalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/.  Its a very nice calendar system which does allow you to attach events to specific dates, etc. I don't believe it does multi-lingual support however so it may not help.  Just offering what I can.

Comment: Thanks Sean. The multi-month and multi-lingual are deal breakers for us, but I do like that calendar. Maybe for future functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Like Sean said in the comments, the best option you have is probably FullCalendar. Although multi-month isn't supported out of the box, you might be able to achieve it by adding multiple calendars. Check out [Issue #199](https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=199&q=multiple&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars), which describes a possible solution.

Regarding the multi-lingual problem: although it isn't multi-lingual by itself, FullCalendar does support modifying the days, months, etc. See [Text/Time Customization](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/). You could use ColdFusion's MonthAsString and DayOfWeekAsString functions to make it multi-lingual yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done with Fullcalendar library

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.8/index.global.min.js"></script>

<script>
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            initialDate: new Date('2023-11-01'),
            initialView: 'multiMonthThreeMonth',
            views: {
                multiMonthThreeMonth: {
                    type: 'multiMonth',
                    duration: { months: 3 }
                }
            },
        });
        calendar.render();
</script>
```